# rollbar not sending exceptions once deployed in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, error-handling, rollbar

I have a project in GAE using python, in which I set up rollbar to track any errors and exceptions. Error reporting worked on localhost, but once I deployed it, my app isn't sending any error log/info that I intentionally created.

I have the rollbar set up as below:

```
import rollbar
rollbar.init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'production')
..
..
#when an error occur
try:
    ....
except:
    rollbar.report_exc_info()
```

UPDATE(11/20):

I'm able to get rollbar to work now, but had to use a older version of requests library (ver 2.3.0). Newer version such as 2.7.0 or 2.8.1 would give me a connection error, anyone knows why or how to get around?

```
ERROR    2015-11-20 17:44:03,543 __init__.py:1158] Exception while posting    item ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Path/to/my/project/rollbar/__init__.py", line 1156, in _send_payload
_post_api('item/', payload, access_token=access_token)
File "/Path/to/my/project/rollbar/__init__.py", line 1197, in _post_api
verify=SETTINGS.get('verify_https', True))
File "/Path/to/my/project/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/Path/to/my/project/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Path/to/my/project/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Path/to/my/project/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Path/to/my/project/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

Comment: Not enough information provided.  Do you see an error in the error log.  How is "rollbar" configured.  It appears to be pure python, so that shouldn't be a problem, Look in your logs and do some basic debugging.  Then provide some more detail.

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://github.com/stickfigure/rollbar-appengine

Comment: @Kekito, that project is for Java. For Python, pyrollbar was updated in version 0.9.7 to support App Engine -- see https://github.com/rollbar/pyrollbar/commit/85c8b18bdba6af12f4fc50de8fda67c939bb6bae . ByTheSea, what version of pyrollbar are you using?

Comment: hi all, Alex,I'm using rollbar ver. 0.11.0.

Comment: for GAE the proper handler should be setup via init method `rollbar.init('xxxxxxx', 'production', handler='gae')`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Rollbar and GAE and the underlying cause was that I was running Google App Engine locally as a normal user that didn't have permissions to open a socket. When I deployed it to Google App Engine, it ran fine.